# SASS/SCSS - Making a selector that will "back out" to modify the parent of the selector

Tags: css, sass

I would like to contain all relevant styles for a selector within a single code block, so that it can be easily referenced.

In my application, a selectors effective styles will be altered dramatically depending on the context in which it sits.  For instance, let's assume this CSS:

```
.container.theme-dark .message
{
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.container.theme-light .message
{
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

Then, imagine I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="container theme-dark">
        <div class="message">Hello World</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container theme-light">
        <div class="message">Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now with SCSS, I would create the relevant CSS like this:

```
.container
{
    &.theme-dark
    {
        .message
        {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
    }

    &.theme-light
    {
        .message
        {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }
    }

    .message
    {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to generate that CSS using SCSS, with all of the relevant information for the .message element in one place.  For instance (using a made-up $ operator that would do what I'm trying to accomplish):

```
.container
{
    .message
    {
        font-size: 16px;

        $.theme-light
        {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }

        $.theme-dark
        {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found this GitHub:
https://github.com/imkremen/sass-parent-append/blob/master/parrent-append.scss

Which I have adapted into this solution:

```
@function str-to-list($string, $separator: ' ', $startAt: 1) 
{
    $workStr: str-slice($string, $startAt);
    $list: ();
    $indexOfFirstSpace: str-index($workStr, $separator);
    @if ($indexOfFirstSpace == null)
    {
        $list: ($workStr);
    }
    @else
    {
        $list: (str-slice($workStr, 1, $indexOfFirstSpace - 1));
        $list: join($list, str-to-list($workStr, $startAt: $indexOfFirstSpace + 1));
    }
    @return $list;
}

@function getBase($appendix)
{
    $parentSelector: str-to-list(#{&});
    $pos: (length($parentSelector) - 1);
    $selector: set-nth($parentSelector, $pos, nth($parentSelector, $pos) + $appendix);
    @return $selector;
}

@mixin base($appendix)
{
    @at-root #{getBase($appendix)}
   {
      @content;
   }
}
```

Which I can then use like this:

```
.container
{
    .message
    {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    @include base(".theme-light")
    {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }

    @include base(".theme-dark")
    {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

which compiles into this:

```
.container .message
{
    font-size: 16px;
}

.container.theme-light .message
{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.container.theme-dark .message
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this might work, and is like what you're saying?  (It would help me currently if you labeled each example as "Ideal CSS output", "Current SCSS, too many `.message` blocks", and "Ideal SCSS format")

```
.container
{
    @at-root .message
    {
        font-size: 16px;

        .theme-light &
        {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }

        .theme-dark &
        {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

With the `@at-root` there, it will generate `.theme-light .message`, which might be too permissive for some usages, so not the ideal solution...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMxjEq

Basically `&` gets replaced with the full tree-path, so `.container .message`, which without `@at-root`, will generate `.theme-light .container .message`, which does not work with the structure.  Perhaps also consider this, which makes a reasonable compromise I would say:

```
.container
{
    .message
    {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    @at-root .message
    {
        .theme-dark
        {
            ...
        }

        .theme-light
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

It's [apparently a kind of hacky solution](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-8), but apparently works

[This page might have some better guidance as well](https://codeburst.io/how-to-do-sass-grandparent-selectors-b8666dcaf961)

Comment: I’m thinking that I’m going to somehow incorporate the at-root function but it isn’t very nicely documented and i can’t figure out a clean way to implement it?

Comment: Just updated with `@at-root`, which works with your current HTML, although is much less restricted (will match any `.message` on the page)  I didn't realize that `&` gets replaced with the full tree-path, so `.container .message` in this case unless `@at-root` is used

Comment: Hmmm it’s still not perfect - is love to avoid repeating the .message selector - have you ever worked with all of the options for at-root? Maybe there is a way to go one level up and select from there?

Answer (score 1):

This organization can be achieved if you use sass programatically:

```
$themes: light dark;

.container {
    @for $i from 1 through length($themes) {
        &.theme-#{nth($themes,$i)} {
            .message {
                font-size: 16px;
                @if nth($themes,$i) == light {
                    background-color: white;
                    color: black;
                } @else if nth($themes,$i) == dark {
                    background-color: black;
                    color: white;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This generates:

```
.container.theme-light .message {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
.container.theme-dark .message {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

The nested looping automatically groups the details at each level in the same block of code. This also scales to multiple levels of nesting. The critical point is that at inner loops you can reference the selectors of outer loops.

Comment: This is even more complicated!  I'm trying to figure out a repeatable, simple pattern that is easy to read!

Comment: Conventional sass is a hierarchical view of css where the children of a container are grouped together. You want the children of different containers to be physically close in the source file. Although, you may find an ad hoc way that may work for some particular circumstances I really don't see it can work in general because of the hierarchical nature of sass. The programmatic view however natural groups elements at the same container level in the same loop  context and this will easily scale.

Comment: Although the programmatic view is different and may seem strange I think to a programmer it is quite natural and will be easier to understand then the hierarchical view for really complex css.

Comment: So the "theme" example was just an example - the actual stuff that I want to use this for is a lot more complex - that's why I need something more basic.  There is now way for me to apply a solution where I iterate over a list of pre-defined options like this